# I can't find the app manifest file (WP8)

Tags: windows-phone-8

I'm having troubles finding the app manifest file in a Windows Phone 8 Project, I tried searching for "Properties", but there's not such folder in my project, I tryed seeing under "My Project" but there's nothing in there.
Someone knows how to help me?

[image: Screenshot of "Solution Explorer"]

P.S. The app works just fine so I think there must be a manifest file in the project, am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VB projects hide these files - they show if you set to show all files, and you can also change the settings via the project properties, without needing to open them.